# How to get git commit sha1 using kubectl cmd?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

How can I using kubectl cmd to get specific pod's commit sha1 like:

```
kubectl get git_commit_sha1 [pod_name]
```

Comment: I don't think you can get this directly; I wouldn't expect a given pod to have either the `git` tool or the `.git` directory, and for that matter it might use a source control system like Mercurial or Subversion instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to achieve what you want at the moment using kubectl. They only possible way would be if your docker image have `git` command built in. In that case you could use `kubectl exec` to get the information you want.

Example:

```
$ kubectl exec -ti podname -- git show
```

Alternatively, if you really think your idea makes sense and may be useful to more people, you can open a feature request on [kubernetes github issues page](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues).