# How can I get the answers for specific users via the Stack Exchange API?

Tags: python, stackexchange-api

I want to count the number of answers for some specific users within a certain time range.I can't find the answers for those, though. The following script doesn't return anything:

```
from stackapi import StackAPI
from pprint import pprint
user_list = [12153576, 11148139]
SITE = StackAPI('stackoverflow')
answers = SITE.fetch('answers',fromdate=1591488000, todate=1591747200)
user_ids = SITE.fetch("users/{ids}", ids=user_list)
for user in user_ids['items']:
    for ans in answers['items']:
        if user['user_id'] == ans['owner']['user_id']:
            pprint(ans['owner']['display_name'])
```

Answers do exist, however, for example: [user 12153576's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62262655) and [user 11148139's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62263562).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [answers on users](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-users) (aka `users/{ids}/answers`) as you mentioned. After passing the `fromdate` parameter to the request, you should get the length of the `items` returned.

Currently, there is a bug with Stack Exchange and [`total` will always be 0](https://github.com/AWegnerGitHub/stackapi/blob/009f3fba11a45d5f240df14aa523356ee80b78bb/docs/user/complex.rst#L36). You can use `len`, though instead of a counter and a `for` loop, since those make the script inefficient.

```
from stackapi import StackAPI

user_list = [12153576, 11148139]
fromdate = 1591488000
SITE = StackAPI('stackoverflow')

answers = SITE.fetch('users/{ids}/answers', ids = user_list, fromdate = fromdate)
print(len(answers['items']))
```

Answer (score 1):

Came up with following solution

```
from stackapi import StackAPI
from pprint import pprint
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
user_list = [12153576, 11148139]
fromdate=1591488000
cnt = 0    
SITE = StackAPI('stackoverflow')

answers = SITE.fetch('users/{ids}/answers', ids=user_list)
for ans in answers['items']:
    if (ans['creation_date']) > fromdate:
        cnt = cnt + 1
print("cnt:", cnt)
```